# Gear display on MFI Volkswagen Polo Highline right drive cars

Tags: vw, transmission, polo, indicators

I'm a new driver, and often get into the wrong gear (I'm not yet comfortable with the multitude of controls in this car which is a 2011 VW Polo Highline).

Is it  possible to show the current gear info on the MFI?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a manual shift vehicle?

Comment: If you have to look to see which gear you are in then that is taking your eyes off the road and that is not good... So, this comes down to practise... well IMHO anyway

Comment: To those who have VTC, how is this a driving technique question? They're asking how to display the current gear the transmission is in. Voting to leave open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't possible, there are many configurations and things that can be activated on the Instrument Cluster but displaying the current gear on manual vehicles isn't possible.

I know you probably don't want to hear this but there is really no need to have a gear display on a conventional manual. If you ask any experienced driver they will tell you that you don't even need to know what gear you're in (apart from 1st or reverse obviously).

It just comes down to experience and practice. Keep changing gear for the sake of it and practice going up and down the gears. When you get used to it you will also realise that the thought 'what gear am I in' will never enter you head. You just change up when the revs are high and down when they're low.

Comment: How do we know this is a manual shift tranny?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a manual gearbox (since you're unlikely to be worrying about gear selection on a DSG since you can just leave it in Drive)

I believe the current/suggested gear info display (or "visual gear indicator" in VW parlance) was only present on the Bluemotion versions of the car (to tie in with the eco theme).